# QGIS Modeler: Extract by location, multiple predicates

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler, spatial-query

I'm creating a processing model and would like to use the 'extract by location' tool,

The problem is that when I choose this tool from the 'Algorithms' in the model creator, I cant find the double criteria as we can find in the one in the QGIS toolbox (normal use). The model creator gives an 'extract by location' with only one criterion.

Is there any way to have many criteria in the same query?

[image]
[image]

Comment: which QGIS version is that? Are you running any other algorithms before/after `"Extract by location"`?

Comment: You are missing a `[...]` button to the right. It is there in my modeler and can be used to select multiple predicates. But I have version 3.12.2

Comment: @BERA are you working with the same version plz ?

Comment: Cant you Select by Location then work with the selection? If the button is available in that tool (it is for me)

Comment: @BERA I don't have that button in both of of them 'select by location' and 'extract by location' :(

Comment: @Taras I am working wtih the 3.4.12 version , yes there are other algorithms before and after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version I am using is qgis (3.4.12)and doesn't support multiple predicates.

The simplest way I found is to use multiple 'select by location' algorithms. in each one, one predicate is used, and the selection must be added to the previous one.

the last algorithm is to 'extract selected features'

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded 2.18.28, 3.4.12, 3.10.5, and version 3.4.12 does not have the option in the processing Modeler to choose more than 1 geometric predicate. When clicking the help button you will be transferred to:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbylocation

In the user manual it indeed claims to have the possibility to choose more than one condition. However, I looked at the algorithm in the Processing Modeler quite extensively but there is no option to do this. If you want to keep working with 3.4.12 I suggest you write/copy a python script which will execute the correct algorithm for you.

You will get something like this where the predicate you want has a number corresponding with the link I posted above.

```
  # Extract by location
    alg_params = {
        'INPUT': 'C:/Users/Dominator/Documents/Backup Hardeschijf/Studie Geschiedenis/Project Diocesen/GIS MASTER/QGIS - AFRICA REGION/GIS_AFRICA_FILES/COASTLINE_AFRICA.dbf.shp',
        'INTERSECT': 'C:/Users/Dominator/Documents/Backup Hardeschijf/Studie Geschiedenis/Project Diocesen/GIS MASTER/QGIS - AFRICA REGION/GIS_AFRICA_FILES/COASTLINE_AFRICA_NEW.shp',
        'PREDICATE': [0,3,1,2,4,5,6,7],
        'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
    }
    outputs['ExtractByLocation'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
    return results
```